# Collision between two identical particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, tensor-calculus, identical-particles

I was working on the exercises of the identical particles chapter of Cohen-Tannoudji, and got stuck due to some conceptual flaws. My questions are numbered below. In the problem, there are two particles, with the same mass, assumed to have no spin, and to be distinguishable. They interact through a potential $V(r)$, where $r$ is the distance between them. The initial state is $\left| 1: p \textbf{z}; 2: -p \textbf{z} \right>$. I'm supposed to prove that

$F(\textbf{n}) = \left< 1: p \textbf{n}; 2: -p \textbf{n} \right|U(t, t_{0})\left| 1: p \textbf{z}; 2: -p \textbf{z}\right>$,

where $\textbf{n} =  \sin(\theta)\cos(\phi)\textbf{x} + \sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)\textbf{y} + \cos(\theta)\textbf{z}$, doesn't depend on $\phi$.

First, I wrote the Hamiltonian

$H = \frac{p_{1}^{2}}{2m} + \frac{p_{2}^{2}}{2m} + V(r)$,

and the time evolution operator

$U(t, t_{0}) = e^{-iHt/\hbar}$.

I would like to write the exponential as a product of exponentials, but I couldn't calculate the commutator $[p_{i}^2, V(r)]$, ***(1) is this a known result for central force problems?*** (edit: I think this is not actually a central force problem...)

I would also like to write the state $\left< 1: p \textbf{n}; 2: -p \textbf{n} \right|$ in terms of $\theta$ and $\phi$. I'm a little new to tensor algebra, but ***(2) is the expression below correct?***

$\left< 1: p \textbf{n}; 2: -p \textbf{n} \right| = \left<1: p\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi)\textbf{x} \right| + \left<1: p\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)\textbf{y}\right| + \left<1: p \cos(\theta)\textbf{z}\right| \otimes \left<2: p\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi)\textbf{x} \right| + \left<2: p\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)\textbf{y}\right| + \left<2: p \cos(\theta)\textbf{z}\right|$

I think I should show that only the terms with $\textbf{z}$ in this bra survives in $F(\textbf{n})$, but I don't really know what to do with the time evolution operator, ***(3) how does it act on the ket?***

Any help or advice will be very appreciated.

Comment: 1) You can calculate $[p,F(X)]$ as $-i\hbar \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$